# How to consolidate users in windows server 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, permissions, users

I'm new to Windows Server.  Sorry for the beginner question.

At work (4 employees, ~10 computers), I've set up an AD on one of our servers.  Before I did this, I created accounts/logins for each employee on each computer.  Is there a way to consolidate these logins using AD.  This way, each user has one password that they can change and get access to all the computers they have permissions to access?

Related, how do you set which users can access which computers?  Is that in the AD configuration?

Thanks for any help.  Sorry, I don't even know what key words to search for, or if this is even possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a special setting in AD user configuration to specify list of workstation/servers this user can log on to.

Check "Profile" tab of user account settings and use button 'Log on to..." for it. By default it set to "All computers" but you can specify here a computer(s) only allowed to use for this  user.

Please note - this restrictions apply to domain users logon only to a domain computers (hope you joined your workstations to created domain?)

Comment: Thanks for the info.  All my computers are on the same domain.  Where can I learn more about domain users? I don't know what that means.

Comment: Domain users = users you created in AD.

Comment: You can read about Active Directory Services in Windows 2008 here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsserver/dd448614